# How to use variable defined inside main.py file into another file?

Tags: python, import, module, program-entry-point

This is my first month as a programmer, so I was creating a replica of movie booking site. I have written some code in my `main.py` file:

```
def main():
    current_income=0
    print('---->Enter the number of row in Cinemahall :- ')
    while True:
        try:
            row=int(input())
            break
        except:
            print('-->Something went wrong!! Please enter the valid row in cinemahall. The value must be integer type :')
    print("---->Enter the number of column in Cinemahall :- ")
    while True:
        try:
            col=int(input())
            break
        except:
            print('-->Something went wrong!! Please enter the valid column in cinemahall. The value must be integer type :')

    while True:
        import options_movies
        options_movies.options()
        break

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Now I have another file `options.py`:

```
def options():

    while True:
        print('1. show the seats')
        print('2. buy a ticket')
        print('3. statistics')
        print('4. show booked ticked user info')
        print('0. exit')
        print('--> Please select one option from 1,2,3,4,0 ')
        ##try:
        n=int(input())
        if n==1:
            from main import main
            import show_seats
            show_seats.show_the_seats(main.row,main.col)
        elif n==2:
            import buy_ticket
            buy_ticket.buy_a_ticket()
        elif n==3:
            import statistics
            statistics.statistics()
        elif n==4:
            import user_info
            user_info.booked_ticket_user_info()
        elif n==0:
            print('Thank you for using BOOK MY SHOW,We hope you will enjoy the show...... Please visit again!!')
            break
                ##assert n>=0 and n<=4
       ## except:
           ## print('Something went wrong!!!! Please enter the valid option from 1,2,3,4,0')
```

Now when I am trying to use to row and col value in show_seats.show_the_seats() from main.py file I am getting this error

```
  File "C:\Users\ROHIT KUMAR VERMA\OneDrive\Documents\Book My Show Project\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ROHIT KUMAR VERMA\OneDrive\Documents\Book My Show Project\main.py", line 20, in main
    options_movies.options()
  File "C:\Users\ROHIT KUMAR VERMA\OneDrive\Documents\Book My Show Project\options_movies.py", line 16, in options
    show_seats.show_the_seats(main.row,main.col)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'row'
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: The `import` statements should be at the start of your script. A `while` loop with an unconditional `break` is no loop. Your functions need parameters for the values they need and a `return` to give back vakues from the function. All in all: take a step back and learn how imports and functions work.

Comment: @Matthias I am importing module when any if or elif condition satisfy. while loop will break only when I will enter 0. Moreover I have tried all things you are telling but problem remain same..

Answer (score 0):

Variables that are created inside a function can only be used inside that function.
You need to create global variables:

```
my_variable = "awesome"

def myfunc():
  print("Python is " + my_variable)

myfunc()
```

Now, you can just import the variable in the file you need it:

```
from filename import variable
```

refs:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp
- https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-import-variables-from-another-file-in-python

Comment: Your answer will lead to the use of [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) and using `global` is in most cases a very, very bad idea.

Comment: From what i understood, he doesn't want to modify the variables

Comment: @FelipeCarvalho thank you for your suggestion , but row and col are taking value from user and I am using that value in 7 modules. when I am writing main.py file without `if __name__=='__main__`:` I am able to achieve what I want , but by doing this when I am importing main file, it is getting executed instead of just importing variable. And if am using  `if __name__=='__main__`:` I am getting this error. I hope I am more clear this time.